# PyGObject Problems with a ComboBoxEntry

Tags: python, gtk, glade, pygobject

I'm having a problem with a `ComboBoxEntry` and the function that populates it.

This is the `__init__` code on the GUI.

```
self.combobox_category = self.builder.get_object("combobox_category")
self.combobox_category.set_entry_text_column(1)
INIT_COMBOBOX_category(self)
```

And this is the function that populates the `ComboBoxEntry`.

```
def INIT_COMBOBOX_category(self):

    self.list_category = Gtk.ListStore(int,str)
    self.list_category.clear()

    self.list_category.append([0,"< List all the categories >"])
    self.list_category.append([1,"No specified"])

    #...No relevant code...

    self.combobox_category.set_model(self.list_category)
    self.cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    self.combobox_category.pack_start(self.cell, True)
    self.combobox_category.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 1)
    self.combobox_category.set_active(1)
```

The problem is that when I start the GUI, the `combobox_category` has "duplicated values"
(only when selecting values, not in the `ComboBoxEntry`):

```
< List all the categories > < List all the categories >
No specified                No specified
```

And then, when I need to use the function `INIT_COMBOBOX_category(self)` again the values are tripled, etc.

I think that

```
self.list_category.clear()
```

is not working.

It is also strange that in Glade, I selected the `ComboBoxEntry` as "editable" and I cannot write on it. I also tried as "Overwrite Mode" and it's still not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, It consists in making the ComboBoxEntry in python instead of glade, in the **init** function the ComboBoxEntry is created, and in the INIT_COMBOBOX_category the ListStore is modified.

the **init** code is the folowing:

```
self.list_category=Gtk.ListStore(int,str)
self.category_combo=Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(self.list_category)
self.category_combo.show()
self.box_category_to_install.add(self.category_combo)
self.category_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
INIT_COMBOBOX_category(self)
```

( i added a box in glade, called box_category_to_install to place the ComboBoxEntry )

and

```
def INIT_COMBOBOX_category(self):

    self.list_category.clear()
    self.list_category.append([0,"< List all the categories >"])
    self.list_category.append([1,"No specified"])
    etc...
```